# How to install missing woocommerce pages from tools menu in woocommerce 2.1.5

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I have recently installed WooCommerce 2.1.5 that skipped logout and change password links during pages install.

In WooCommerce documentation, the WooCommerce team mentioned that there is a feature to add missing pages from tools menu but when I go to the tools menu, I don't see any button to install missing pages.

How can I get it done?

Is there any step I have missed?

Do I need to install a plugin in order to get that button showing in the tools menu?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This can be done by:

1. Go to the "System Status" tab on Woocommerce
2. Click on the "Tools" tab at the top of the page
3. On that page, the ninth  option down is called "create pages".
4. Clicking that will "install all the missing WooCommerce pages. Pages
   already defined and set up will not be replaced."

Comment: Thats the correct way but still after pressing the install pages button I cannot see change password and logout page in pages

Comment: Could they be in the second/third page of pages?

Comment: I just checked mine and using that option doesn't actually install all the pages :/ http://docs.woothemes.com/document/pages-not-displaying/ that page has a list of shortcodes for the different pages as a last resort.

Answer (score 8):

install missing woocommerce pages
 Woocommerce->Status -> Tools ->Install WooCommerce Pages

Install pages Note: This tool will install all the missing WooCommerce pages. Pages already defined and set up will not be replaced.

WooCommerce > 2.1.x Shortcodes:

```
[woocommerce_cart] – shows the cart page
[woocommerce_checkout] – shows the checkout page
[woocommerce_order_tracking] – shows the order tracking form
[woocommerce_my_account] – shows the user account page
```

WooCommerce < 2.1.x Shortcodes:

```
[woocommerce_edit_account] – Edit account pages
[woocommerce_change_password] – shows the change password page
[woocommerce_view_order] – shows the user account view order page
[woocommerce_logout] – shows the logout page
[woocommerce_pay] – shows the checkout pay page
[woocommerce_thankyou] – shows the order received page
[woocommerce_lost_password] – shows the lost password page
[woocommerce_edit_address] – shows the user account edit address page
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me regarding missing cart or 404 error message when clicking view cart and how I fixed it.

Step 1.

Create new page and call it Cart. If cart page already exist WP will automatically call it cart-2 or whatever.

Step 2 
Add [woocommerce_cart] shortcode on the page.

Step 3. Publish this page.

Step 4. Now go to woocommerce-->settings--->checkout---> look for check out pages--->under cart looku for cart page . Now save changes.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your old pages have been deleted from the pages trashcan. I was having the same problem reinstalling. I checked the trashcan and my old pages were there. I emptied the trash bin and was able to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hard job to uninstall woocommerce plugin, when you have products in it.

The easiest way to have your woocommerce pages back, is;

1. Install woocommerce on some other instance, say on a sub-domain of
   the same site and configure it. woocommerce pages will be installed.
2. Install WordPress Import/Export Plugin.
3. From WordPress Tools menu select Export->Pages->All and download the
   file, that will be in xml format.
4. Now, restore this xml file on your original domain thru WordPress
   Tools menu by selecting Import->Wordpress.

and that is.

Your woocommerce pages are back.

GoodLuck!

Answer (score 0):

In case you have trouble installing woocommerce pages using the tool tab (I was getting the following error: `Page ID is set, but the page does not exist`) you can also try creating and setting them manually in woocommerce:

- Create new page, name it **Cart**, **Checkout** or whatever page you want to create that is missing in Woocommerce
- In page content insert Shortcode and use any of these WooCommerce shortcodes, more info on https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/, some examples:

  `[woocommerce_cart] - shows the cart page`

  `[woocommerce_checkout] – shows the checkout page`

  `[woocommerce_my_account] – shows the user account page`

  `[woocommerce_order_tracking] – shows the order tracking form`
- Manually set the page you just created in `Woocommerce -> Settings -> Advanced -> Page Setup`